# Django- passing object in context for view works, but how to pass to include?

Tags: django

UPDATED THANKS TO FEEDBACK: I'm including a template where I have access to the logged in user, but I'd like to be able to access that user's corresponding Person record (linked by a Profile model I made for supplemental fields), so I can show a little link to their page in the top nav. I can get that Person record for individual views in views.py, but my top_nav.html (template, or 'partial' in the laravel/rails worlds) gets included without using views.py so I'm not sure how to get/pass extra items to the template without views.py (and don't want to repeat passing the person to EVERY view that includes the top nav). I'd love to be able to add a method on Users, so I could access it like user.get_person, but extending auth.User looks like a nightmare.

---

I'm making my first Django app I can pass/access a variable for the request user in one view but not another (partial/template) view.

The details: I have a partial for my top navbar, where I want to include a link to the 'person page' for the logged in user. I even pass along the user when I include that partial view, though I'm not sure how to access it in views.py. In views.py, I can pass along a QuerySet for the user for the person_index view using request.user, but that's not available in  top_nav. I'm not sure if/how I can somehow grab the user in views.py from it being included when I call that top_nav from base.html?

The person index view is set up like this:

- person_index.html extends base.html
- base.html includes the top_nav.html
- then the 'meat' of the view is in {% block content %}

See views.py below: I grab the person for person_index (the face_link partial works), but obviously I don't want to get/pass it for EVERY view, instead I want to do it once and be able to pass it along to top_nav.html.

views.py:

```
def person_index(request):
    accessible_branches = get_valid_branches(request)
    this_person = get_user_person(request.user).first()
    person_list = Person.objects.order_by('display_name') 
    context = { 'person_list': person_list,
                'accessible_branches':accessible_branches, 'this_person': this_person}
    return render(request, 'familytree/person_index.html', context)

def get_user_person(user):
    try:
        this_user_person = Person.objects.filter(profile__user_id=user)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        this_user_person = None
    return this_user_person
```

top_nav.html: (I'd like to be able to get/pass the person record)

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Home</a>
        <a href="{% url 'family_index' %}">Families</a>
        <a href="{% url 'person_index' %}">People</a>
        {%  if this_person %}
            {% include "familytree/face_link.html" with person=this_person %}
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

base.html: (the user record is available 'for free', need to get its corresponding profile__person)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
        Our big family tree
           {% block title %}
           {{ page_title|default:"Untitled Page" }}
          {% endblock title %}
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'familytree/style.css' %}">

{#    Top nav#}
    {% include "familytree/top_nav.html" with user=user %} <br/>

{#  Separator line#}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <hr class = "line" />
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{#  Page content#}
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
            <p>Placeholder text in base template- this gets replaced with page content.</p>
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there something I'm missing about to properly pass/get the user for this partial include? Are there rules about who can load what?

Comment: Are you sure this line `this_user_person = Person.objects.filter(profile__user_id=user)` return something?

Comment: thanks Wariored- hmmm... I do use the same method by each view, but it could possibly give different responses if the request for one had a user and the request for the other did not... I'll see if I can confirm...

Comment: Wariored that was it! And I forgot that the base.html called top nav specifically with one user (and only that)- my mistake!

Comment: "but not another (partial) view." => If this is supposed to be some rails-like definition of "partial", this doesn't exist in django. Hint: you may want to use a custom template tag to avoid repeated code.

Comment: Template inclusion does not invoke a view. `include "familytree/top_nav.html" with user=user` top_nav is expecting `this_person`, not `user`.

Comment: Ivan Starostin thank you- you're right!! I can comment out top_nav in views.py and there's no change at all!  User was available 'for free'... so I need to figure out how/where to grab the person for the logged in user. (I made a Profile class for extra fields associated with the user, approach 2 here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html). I'd LIKE to define a method for user that can get_user_person (via Profile and Person), but I'm wondering if I'll need to switch to option 1 or 3 (proxy model, or custom model) in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
def top_nav(request):
    this_user_person = Person.objects.get(profile__user=request.user)
    context = { 'this_user_person': this_user_person}
    return render(request, 'familytree/top_nav.html', context)
```

in templates you can call

```
{{ this_user_person.first_name }}
```

Comment: thanks, bmons! That didn't change the symptoms any, but it's less messy so I'll update my code accordingly

Comment: I have updated the answer with a get call, try it otherwise

Comment: one another way is you can get request.user.profile.first_name in any templates

Comment: thanks bmons- I think the issue is it's easy to get these objects within views.py, but my top_nav.html is 'included' in base.html, so it doesn't make use of views.py, so I have to find some *other* way to retrieve the Person object for this user